# Expected Decleration

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried to resolve this. I have looked at others with the same problems but it didn't solve anything.

I get the "expected declaration" error on the line:

```
super.viewDidLoad(){
```

Code:

```
super.viewDidLoad(){  

    score = 0
    Bluelbl.text = "\(score)"
    Redlbl.text = "\(score)"

    Bluelbl.transform  = CGAffineTransform (rotationAngle: 3.14)

    Restart.transform  = CGAffineTransform (rotationAngle: 1.57)
    TopEndLbl.transform = CGAffineTransform (rotationAngle: 3.14)
    EndScene.isHidden = true
    TopEndLbl.isHidden = true
    BtmEndLbl.isHidden = true
    Restart.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: where you write this function

Comment: FYI - It is standard practice in Swift to name methods and variables starting with lowercase letters. This includes outlets.

Answer (score 2):

Correct declaration

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    //
 }
```

Comment: Thanks man :))))

Answer (score 2):

The function declaration is not correct.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    score = 0
    Bluelbl.text = "\(score)"
    Redlbl.text = "\(score)"

    Bluelbl.transform  = CGAffineTransform (rotationAngle: 3.14)

    Restart.transform  = CGAffineTransform (rotationAngle: 1.57)
    TopEndLbl.transform = CGAffineTransform (rotationAngle: 3.14)
    EndScene.isHidden = true
    TopEndLbl.isHidden = true
    BtmEndLbl.isHidden = true
    Restart.isHidden = true
}
```